# How dependency injection using annotation works internally whether it calls to setter methods or constructor based injection

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, annotations

```
    @Component
    public class Address 
    {

        @Value("Delhi")
        private String city;

        public String getCity()
        {
             return city;
        }
     }
```

Above code doesn't have any setter method or parameterized constructor in class and city is private member of class so it doesn't have and way to initialize city except hard code the value. When i run the code bean is instantiated with value "Delhi" and is get printed. Can some one explain me how annotation setting the value of private member without calling setter or constructor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spring uses reflection for this . Doesn't matter whether its a private or public member . Please refer a simple explanation [here](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/private-fields-and-methods.html)